# Asp.net core 3. Problem in hosting app in IIS and development side by side

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-3.0

I have recently updated my asp.net core 2.1 application to .net core 3.0
On my development my machine i have hosted my application on IIS so that some other components consume it and whenever i need to debug i simply debug it.
Previously my web.config was

```
<aspNetCore processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" stdoutLogEnabled="false" />
```

After upgrade my web.config seems like

```
<aspNetCore processPath="D:\MyApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\MyApp.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess" />
```

My application only accessible to outside when i debug the application.
Any think i am missing

Comment: "My application only accessible to outside when i debug the application." That's controlled by your site bindings.

Comment: you could see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54779630/migrate-from-asp-net-core-2-0-to-3-0) and follow the process of how to migrate site from asp.net core 2.1 to 3

Comment: site is migrated and up and running. i have even deployed and checked it on both windows and Linux. here my question is regarding one changed observed in development environment

Comment: could you share how you migrated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516574/asp-net-core-2-1-to-asp-net-3-0-upgrade

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by your application is not accessible outside? the hostingModel will automatically be added when you upgrade the .net core. could you please explain what is your exact requirement and what error you are facing?

Comment: I have a development machine where i have hosted my .net core 2.1 application on IIS. previously what i see in the processPath was mentioned in the post. then i have updated the application to .net core 3.1. my config has changed . i have to start one debug ging session to let other's access my virutal directory. which was not the case in .net 2.1

Comment: can you visit the site locally? do you hosted site in iis?

Comment: yes i have deployed the site on IIS viritual directory. I can access the application after starting debugging session. locally or remote. After certain time of closing the session. i can't access the api's. May be IIS app domain has recycled and it doesn't start the new process on new request which comes without debugging